# CentOS 7.2 dbus can't active polkit but can start polkit service manual

Tags: centos, systemd, d-bus, polkit

I just use CentOS 7.2, and default systemd version (systemd 219) used by CentOS 7.2;
I just find my physical host, `systemctl` command can not use.
eg. if I execute `systemctl restart syslog-ng` it will be stuck.

And only reboot can solve this problem.

```
[root@localhost /root]
#time systemctl restart syslog-ng
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to restart syslog-ng.service: Connection timed out

real   0m25.031s
user   0m0.004s
sys    0m0.003s
```

So , I just find that polkit actived by dbus failed.

```
[root@localhost /root]
#time systemctl restart polkit
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Activation of org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 timed out (g-dbus-error-quark, 20)

Job for polkit.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status polkit.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

real   1m33.771s
user   0m0.003s
sys    0m0.005s
```

busctl cann't see problems

```
[root@localhost /root]
#busctl
NAME                              PID PROCESS         USER             CONNECTION    UNIT                      SESSION    DESCRIPTION
:1.4                            74375 polkitd         polkitd          :1.4          polkit.service            -          -
:1.7                            75062 busctl          root             :1.7          sshd.service              -          -
net.reactivated.Fprint              - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.DBus                - -               -                -             -                         -          -
org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1      74375 polkitd         polkitd          :1.4          polkit.service            -          -
org.freedesktop.hostname1           - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.locale1             - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.login1              - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.machine1            - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.systemd1            - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
org.freedesktop.timedate1           - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
```

But, if I manually start polkit, everting gonna be OK, systemctl command can use.

```
[root@localhost /root]
#/usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd
```

And, if I use busctl also can't active polkit. So I think there is bug in dbus?

```
#busctl call org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1 org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager StartUnit ss polkit.service replace
```

Anybody see this problem?
I also checked /etc/passwd exists polkit user account.

Comment: What does the service template look like?